# If statement in Rails Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Can I use an if statement in my controller or is this bad practice?

In both my create and destroy actions for TracksController, I want to do something like this:

```
if Product
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@track = @product.tracks.create(params[:track])

eslif Release
@Release = Release.find(params[:release_id])
@track = @release.tracks.create(params[:track])
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go further and suggest a more DRY approach to the before_filter:

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_track_parent, only: [ :create, :destroy ]

  def create
    @track = @parent.tracks.create(params[:track])
    ...
    redirect_to @parent
  end

  private

  def get_track_parent
    if params[:product_id].present?
      @parent = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    elsif params[:release_id].present?
      @parent = Release.find(params[:release_id])
    end
  end
end
```

I used parent because we were given a context for the model relationships but I assume there's a better term to describe the commonality between release and product wrt tracks.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense, i'll implement this now.

Comment: This seems to work well, except i'm having issues with redirects using this approach. The if and elsif statments contain a 'redirect_to product_path(@product)' or 'redirect_to release_path(@release)'. What's the best way to add those in a DRY way?

Comment: with these methods you just need to supply the variable to redirect_to like so: `redirect_to @parent`

Comment: @RyanBerry I've included the redirect at the end of the create. As Vapire pointed out all you need is the variable.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it via a `before_filter` callback:

```
class TracksController < AC
  before_filter :ensure_track, :only => [ :create, :destroy ]

  private

  def ensure_track
    if Product
      @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
      @track = @product.tracks.create(params[:track])
    elsif Release
      @release = Release.find(params[:release_id])
      @track = @release.tracks.create(params[:track])
    end
  end
end
```

So with this setup it's ensured that you have a @track instance variable in your create and destroy methods, cause `ensure_track` gets invoked before those two methods.

I'm not sure though, if the logic you're applying makes sense... Why do you want to test if a constant named `Product` exists and if not if a constant named `Release` does? Maybe the question should be if either `params[:product_id]` or `params[:release_id]` is present!?

But that's a different question :)

UPDATE: See [Rails Action Controller Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) for filters.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure I understand this but i'll try it out. Regarding the logic; i've basically Release & Product models that both can have tracks, each recorded in Release_Tracks and Product_Tracks HABTM associations/tables. Now i've got this far, i'm actually wondering if I should have taken a different approach and used a Polymorphic association?

Comment: I see... Well I think a polymorphic relation would make sense here. But your above if-statement always defaults to true, cause there always is a constant with the name of `Product` in your namespace, so it will never go in the elsif-path...

Comment: Ah, I understand how the filters work now. I've just remembered why I didn't use a polymorphic associate previously; when a product is created it inherits the tracks associated to it's parent release and I need to maintain the ability to amend the track listing at the product level and add additional 'bonus' tracks that only feature on an individual product. So, i'm back to thinking the original approach is what I need. I just need to make the if statement work.

Comment: Using if params[:product_id].present? as suggested above solved this! Many thanks.